# Can I create a game for webgl without the Unity logo?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Can I create a game for webgl without the Unity logo when I download and without title "Unity webGL"?
 . [example](http://webassembly.org/demo/Tanks/)

Comment: you have to pay for it

Answer (score 8):

[According to the docs you need a Pro license to remove the splash screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsSplashScreen.html). (the logo in the middle of the screen)

As for the frame around the game that's easy to change, just [change the HTML as documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html). You can choose either one of the defaults or create your own template.

According to those docs you create folder in `Assets` called `WebGLTemplates` and inside that create a new folder for your template like `BetterTemplate`. Inside that put an `index.html` file and any other images, css, JavaScript files you want included with your game.

The index.html could look something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>%UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      #gameContainer { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
      canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
    var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/dist.json");
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gameContainer"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Then you pick Edit->Project Settings->Player from the menus and under the WebGL tab choose your template

[image]

[Here's an example that provides a custom logo](https://github.com/greggman/better-unity-webgl-template). The part that's not removable without a Pro license is the "Made with Unity" that appears just before the game starts.

Answer (score 1):

Hide through css the webgl container for as long as the unity logo appears. You can even make a js hook so when the first scene is loaded it informs the js part so you can make it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

With the personal license you are unable to legally remove the Unity splash screen. You need the Plus or Pro license. Plus costs $35 a month, Pro is $125 a month.

The majority of the features of Plus and Pro are not needed for smaller projects and with no hurt your development. All engine features are the same across the board, so you can always develop you game with a personal license.

When it comes time to launch you can buy Plus or Pro and remove the splash screen and take advantage of the performance reporting and analytics features that come with it.

Comment: what i always wanted to ask / confirm is. if i buy pro for a month. publish and discontinue pro next month. thats fine. right?
next year, i wanted to update again. buy pro for a month, publish and call it day. not bad!