# Data path in Unity-WebGL using Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel, unity-webgl

is there any posibilitie how to load files (like css or js) from generated WEBGL
The Path in build html is Release/UnityLoader.js so normally it should be localhost:8000/*folders where are the unity files are stored/Release/UnityLoader. 
But with laravel the url looks like localhost:8000/release/UnityLoader.js and it cant be found.. i cant rewrite the including html file ? Any helps. Thanks)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can make custom HTML templates in Unity. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288040/128511

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.